# Java 11 required, but not found. Might have compilation errors

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I cant run VS Code encountering this issue: "Java 11 required, but not found. Might have compilation errors."

Can somone walk me through how to fix

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkdFs.png)

I thought I have java downloaded I dont know what to do?

Comment: I did try getting the Java Development Kit

Comment: I would install a JDK independently of your IDE. Just download it and *install* it

Comment: @g00se Im sorry can I get like a walk through of how to do that :( Sorry! I kind of dont understand it

Comment: Let me get this straight: you're saying you can't get and install a computer program?

Comment: Yes I can sorry :( but I installed JDK and the issue still didnt resolve

Comment: Installed from RedHat

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are installing a Java 11 JDK, and not a different version, since that's what VS Code is asking for.

If you are on linux, there should be options to install older versions of java documented by your distribution. For example, on arch it would be `sudo pacman -S jdk11-openjdk`. If you are on RedHat, as indicated by your comment, it should be `sudo yum install java-11-openjdk`.

On windows or mac, you should be able to find prebuilt binaries and installers online. [Here](https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/) is one link I found, and there are most likely others you can find online. Just make sure to select JDK 11 for whatever you use to install.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that **JDK 11** or above has been installed on your machine, add the following settings to indicate your JDK path

```
    "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "E:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17.0.5",
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
            "path": "E:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_341",
        },
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-17",
            "path": "E:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17.0.5",
            "default": true,
        }
    ],
```

**java.jdt.ls.java.home**:

> Specifies the folder path to the JDK (***17 or more recent***) used to launch the Java Language Server. This setting will replace the Java extension's embedded JRE to start the Java Language Server.

You can also specify or install a new JDK in the following way

[image]